# Keeping current JSF pagination state when going to another page and coming back to the page that contains the paginator

Tags: jsf, pagination, tomahawk, datascroller

I'm using the Tomahawk t:dataScroller for pagination. It is working really well. There is only one issue that I'll try to explain:

**Page A** contains the t:dataTable, which is paginated with the t:dataScroller. There are links in the dataTable that can redirect me to another page, say **page B**. When I go back from B to A, the state of the pagination is restarted.

What I mean is that, if, in Page A, I'm at the **5th** page, and then move to page B, when I go back to A, I'll be at the **1st** page on A.

Does anyone have gone through this? Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Could you provide the JSF code of the `<t:dataScroller>`?

Comment: Have you fixed this? I'm having a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645865/tdatascroller-not-working-correctly-on-refresh

Answer (score 2):

You can take control of 'first' property of the datatable. What you need to this,

1. Declare a public/protected variable in your session bean,

   `@ManagedBean
   @SessionScoped
   public class DataTableController implements java.io.Serializable {
      protected int first;
           // getters and setters...`
2. Bind it with the 'first' property of datatable

   `<p:dataTable id="results-table" var="result"
         ...
         first="#{dataTableController.first}"`
3. While navigating between the pages, store the 'first' record value using something like this,

   `public void onPageChange(PageEvent event) {
         this.setFirst(((DataTable) event.getSource()).getFirst());
      }`

For more details, follow the link.
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=25399#p80324

BTW Thanks for the comments

Comment: Giving link as a answer is not a good thing, just put it in a comment area.