# t:dataScroller not working correctly on refresh

Tags: jsf, myfaces, tomahawk, datascroller

I'm using t:dataScroller to scroll some data from a t:dataTable and it is working fine except for one thing: every time an action that causes the screen to be refreshed is triggered the t:dataScroller's index is set to 1.

To be more clear: when i'm in the second page (index == 2) and a screen refreshing action triggers, after the refresh, the data of the dataTable is still from index 2 but the dataScroller shows that the page being displayed is the first one.

I'm using the dataScroller this way:

```
<t:dataScroller for="myDataTable" id="myDataScroller" paginator="true"
    paginatorMaxPages="#{myBean.paginatorMxPgs}" 
    pageCountVar="pgCount" pageIndexVar="#{myBean.curPg}"
    actionListener="#{myBean.pgListener}">

<f:facet name="prv">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{myBean.curPg > 1}" />
</f:facet>
<f:facet name="nxt">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{myBean.curPg != pgCount}"/>
</f:facet>
</t:dataScroller>
```

i'm using **tomahawk20-1.1.11.jar** and **myfaces-api-2.0.4.jar**

Answer (score 3):

For setting scroller to firstpage set actionlistener on submit button.

```
<t:commandButton actionListener="#{IFussBean.resetDataScroller}" 
                   action="#{IFussBean.searchLocation}" 
                   image="images/submit-button.png">    
  </t:commandButton>
```

Binding:

if it is datatable

```
<t:dataTable id="data"
             headerClass=""
             footerClass=""
             rowClasses="text_holder"
             columnClasses="search_img,search_txt"
             var="item"
             value="#{IFussBean.searchVideoList}"
             preserveDataModel="false"
             rows= "6"
             binding="#{IFussBean.iFussData}"
 >
```

Declare HtmlDataTable in your Bean,define its setter getter as below:

```
private HtmlDataTable iFussData;
```

Getter and setter

```
 public HtmlDataTable getiFussData() {
        return iFussData;
    }
    public void setiFussData(HtmlDataTable iFussData) {
        this.iFussData = iFussData;
    }
```

Now define ActionListener Method in Bean:

```
public void resetDataScroller(ActionEvent e) {
       if(iFussData!= null) {
           iFussData.setFirst(0);
       }
}
```

Your page will set to first page when you'll do new search.

/******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/
if you are using `<rich:dataGrid>` and your scroller is `<t:dataScroller>` then

```
 <rich:dataGrid 
            id="data"
            var="item" 
            columns="3" 
            elements="6" 
            width="600px"
            value="#{IFussBean.searchVideoList}"
            binding="#{IFussBean.iFussDataGrid}"
    >
```

Declare HtmlDataGrid  in Bean:

```
private HtmlDataGrid iFussDataGrid;
```

Its getter and setter

```
public HtmlDataGrid getiFussDataGrid() {
        return iFussDataGrid;
    }



 public void setiFussDataGrid(HtmlDataGrid iFussDataGrid) {
            this.iFussDataGrid = iFussDataGrid;
        }
```

Now define its action listener in Bean which will invoke on pressing command button for search :

```
 public void resetDataScroller(ActionEvent e) {
               if(iFussDataGrid != null) {
                   iFussDataGrid.setFirst(0);
               }
          }
```

Invoke ActionListener on command button

```
<h:commandButton styleClass="submit-button" actionListener="#{IFussBean.resetDataScroller}" action="#{IFussBean.searchLocation}" image="images/submit-button.png"/>
```

It also give desire result.